# ServiceNow - RestApi search or filter server or CI in CMDB class

Tags: python, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Using ServiceNow API I am trying to filter/search CI based on server name. My code is partially working but not fully. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Issue 1: I have more than 15000 server data but pagination seems not correct in my code. So getting only 1000 records as default.

Issue 2: Tried querying using ci name but thats also not working.

Ref: https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/paris/rest/cmdb-instance-api#cmdb-GET-instance-classname

```
def class_data():

    class_data = []

    # CI Class
    classes = [ "cmdb_ci_win_server", "cmdb_ci_linux_server" ]

    # Set the proper headers
    headers = {"Accept":"application/json"}

    for class_id in classes:
        # Set the request parameters 
        url = 'https://sparc.service-now.com/api/now/cmdb/instance/' + class_id + '?sysparm_offset=sysparm_offset+15000'
        #url = 'https://sparc.service-now.com/api/now/cmdb/instance/' + class_id + '?sysparm_query=name=server1'
        #url = 'https://sparc.service-now.com/api/now/cmdb/instance/' + class_id + '?sysparm_limit=1000&sysparm_offset=2>;rel="next"'
 
        # Make the HTTP request
        response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers)

        # Check for HTTP codes other than 200
        if response.status_code != 200: 
            print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:', response.content)
            exit()
        
        # Decode the XML response into a json dictionary and use the data
        class_data.append(response.json()['result'])

    return class_data
```

Comment: Based on your question and input I've found the following URL working in my production environment `https://{{ INSTANCE }}.service-now.com/api/now/table/{{ TABLE }}?sysparm_query=nameLIKE{{ HOSTNAME }}`. Whereby `INSTANCE='<yourInstance>'`, `TABLE='cmdb_ci_linux_server'` and `HOSTNAME='server1'`.